# Is it possible that Java returns a reference to another variable after applying the cast operator?

Tags: java, casting, reference

I have got three classes.

Parent

```
package sample;

public class Parent {

}
```

Child

```
package sample;

public class Child extends Parent {

}
```

GrandChild

```
package sample;

public class GrandChild extends Child {

}
```

And I run the following code:

```
package sample;

public class Main {

    static Parent parent;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        parent = new GrandChild();

        GrandChild grandChild = getGrandChild();
        GrandChild grandChild2 = getGrandChild();
        System.out.println(grandChild == grandChild2);
    }

    private static GrandChild getGrandChild() {
        return (GrandChild) parent;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to see `false` in the console? I always see true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting doesn't change the object being pointed to.

However, you should not be relying on the `==` operator in your code to compare between two objects (use `equals()` instead).

Is there a particular reason why you need this to work? Or just curiosity?

Comment: Comparing with `==` is perfectly fine here since it is about the same instance.

Comment: _Is there a particular reason why you need this to work? Or just curiosity?_ I would say both :)

Comment: I'd also appreciate if you added a link to the JLS or Oracle docs to your answer. So others will see it's reliable.

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev Sure, see
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6
However, the fact that the reference remains the same is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @MuratK, sure, here it's perhaps fine, but in general, it's bad practice to rely on `==` for comparison instead of `equals()` for objects unless you have a very very good reason to do so. Since this question seems to aim at beginner/intermediate level understanding of concepts in Java, I thought it useful to explicate that here.

Answer (score 4):

The method `getGrandChild()` always returns a reference to the same object; casting an object reference never creates a new object and never modifies an object or reference, so you will never see `false` with this code.

Casting is not some magical way to convert objects from one type to another. It's simply a mechanism to tell the compiler: I have a reference to a particular object here and you have to trust me that this is a `GrandChild` object, and don't give me any type errors. It's a way to get around the type checking that the compiler does.

You should avoid casting as much as possible, because it makes your code less type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will always get `true` until you create a new GrandChild instance and comapre with it. Because both `grandChild` and `grandChild2` is referencing same object.

```
public class A {

    static Parent parent;
    static GrandChild grandChild3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        parent = new GrandChild();        
        grandChild3 = new GrandChild();

        GrandChild grandChild = getGrandChild();
        GrandChild grandChild2 = getGrandChild();
        System.out.println(grandChild == grandChild2); // true
        System.out.println(grandChild == grandChild3); // false
    }

    private static GrandChild getGrandChild() {
        return (GrandChild) parent;
    }

}
```

**Note:** If you want to check whether two object is referencing same object, use `==`. But to check equality according to value, you have to use `equals()`.